# MongoDB: remove item from child collection

Tags: .net, linq, mongodb

I'm trying to remove an item from my a child collection in my MongoDB document.
Here is a simple example:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("4f966b41682dbc1be0c7b640"),
    Firstname: "John",
    Lastname: "Doe",
    Skills: [
        { 
          _id : ObjectId("4f966b3f682dbc1bec7b63c"),
          name: "C#"
        },
        { 
          _id : ObjectId("4f966b3f682dbc1bec7b63c"),
          name: "ASP.NET"
        },
    ]
}
```

I've tried `$pull` and it works fine on the shell, but how can I accomplish this using Linq.

any suggestion is much apprciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull is an update mechanism and cannot be accomplished with Linq.  However, you can drop down into native syntax to accomplish this from the .NET driver.

```
var update = Update.Pull("Skills");
var query = Query.Eq("_id", myObjectId);
collection.Update(query, update);
```

Hopefully, we'll get this to be more strongly typed in the future.  You can see the documentation here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Updatemethod.

Comment: thanks! I was able to figure it out with the help of your post.